# cannot start Rails Server, bundle install not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am on Rails 4.0.0
So, I have created a new app in a new directory: rails new lpd.

I have cd' into the new lpd directory.

bundle install gives me Bundler::GemFileNotFound.

rails s does not start the server.

I cd in to another project that has a Gemfile installed, do a bundle install, that works fine and the rails server starts fine.

I cd back into my new project directory lpd and hit rails s again, no luck.

still GemFileNotFound.

Comment: Are you sure you changed into the lpd directory before running `$bundle install`?  Please confirm that the `lpd/Gemfile` file exists in your project.

Comment: Ok, solved this by adding rails new . and then running bundle install.

Comment: Thanks Powers. I think I'm good now.

Comment: It Tom's answer solved your problem, please accept it as the best answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Gemfile in the project directory.

You can:

A. Create one yourself using a Rails 4.0 Gemfile as a template.

B. Copy one over from another Rails 4.0 project.

C. Run `rails new` again to recreate the project files (be careful to backup any changes you have already made such as configuration changes).